# Colours for Notepad++

Tags: fonts, notepad++

Am I able to set font colours in Notepad++ (I don't mean the styles/tag conventions via the Style Configurator; I mean simple text highlighting like in Word or similar)? I'm guessing "no" is the answer, since it is not a word processor, but just wanted to cover all bases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not a word processor, it's a text editor. If you want colours and stuff like that, use Word, Wordpad, or the FOSS favourite OpenOffice.org.